# CORS issue with Twitter api calls in Webpack dev server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, twitter, webpack, cors

I'm running into an issue getting responses from the twitter api (using npm package Twitter).  In Chrome I am getting:

> Failed to load https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=node.js: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

So I enable CORS with a plugin and the error changes to:

> Failed to load https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=node.js: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400.

I'm not sure what to do at this point.  I have tried a couple different things in my webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        contentBase: './src',
        port: 3000,
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
        },
        proxy: {
            "/api": "http://localhost:3000"
        }
    },
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    entry: './dev/js/index.js',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loaders: ['babel'],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
            },
            {
                loader: 'json-loader',
                test: /\.json$/ 
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: 'src',
        filename: 'js/bundle.min.js'
    },
    node: {
        console: false,
        fs: 'empty',
        net: 'empty',
        tls: 'empty'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
        new Dotenv({
            path: './.env',
            safe: false
        })
    ]
};
```

This is the call I'm trying to make

```
import Twitter from 'twitter';

const client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
  consumer_secret: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
  bearer_token: process.env.TWITTER_BEARER_TOKEN
});

client.get('search/tweets', {q: 'node.js'}, function(error, tweets, response) {
   console.log(tweets);
});
```

I tried it in firefox as well with a CORS plugin enabled and I get this error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=node.js. (Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed).

Answer (score 1):

I can think only of a workaround:

- Use the chrome extension [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en)
- Use proxy: instead of accessing `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=node.js`, use a proxy like `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/` as a prefix: `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=node.js`

Comment: Hmmm.. am I doing this proxy right in webpack? proxy: {"/api": "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/"} I added that to my devServer object but it doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I don't think this will work because things like cors-anywhere doesn't allow for Authentication Headers

Comment: @GeraldWangley `devServer.proxy` is not designed for this kind of situation.It is designed to proxy the request to webpack-dev-server to any url you configured. Since the `Twitter` client is requesting https://api.twitter.com directly, your `devServer.proxy` will not  have any effect.        Just try what @Rahamin listed here, either install a browser CORS extension or use an external CORS proxy service.

Answer (score 1):

I was doing it on react. I had the same problem, and what I did to get around that was to mount an express server in node, make test end point, require twitter and follow the steps on the npm site. Then I would hit the express end point with a fetch request on the front end, which in turn would gather data from twitter, and then would send the response from twitter back to the front end.

I ran the express server on localhost:4000 and my create-react-app on localhost:3000, and I went to package.json to add `"proxy": "http://localhost:4000"` above `"scripts" : {}` (doesn't really matter where though).

Worked like a charm ^_^

Comment: Example code are always nice. Could you please provide us with it?

Answer (score 0):

Your browser sets an origin header when making the HTTP request to your webpack dev server proxy and the proxy forwards this origin header to Twitter. Most likely Twitter will reject the request based on its illegal origin. You can get around this by removing the origin header before the request is forwarded:

```
devServer: {
  ...,
  proxy: {
    ...,
    onProxyReq: function onProxyReq(proxyReq, req, res) {
      proxyReq.removeHeader("origin")
    }
  }
}
```