# Using Google Maps Client with cors

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-api-3, codesandbox

I am using the the node.js client library by Google , found here - https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js, in my React component. I am trying to use the Google Distance Matrix in this function:

```
googleMapsClient.distanceMatrix({
  origins: "1002 Deming Way, Madison, WI 53717",
  destinations: that.state.deliverycoords,
  units: "imperial"
}, function(err, response){
  if (err){
    console.log("Error: ", err);
  } else {
     that.setState(
      {
        delivery: Object.assign({}, that.state.delivery, {
          time: response.rows.elements[0].duration.text,
          miles: response.rows.elements[0].distance.text,
          deliveryFeeTotal:
            parseInt(response.rows.elements[0].distance.text.split(" ")[0]) *
            that.state.deliveryFeePerMile
        })
      },
      function() {
        console.log("Retrieved duration: ", that.state.delivery.time);
        console.log("Retrieved miles:", that.state.delivery.miles);
        console.log(
          "Retrieved total delivery fee: ",
          that.state.delivery.deliveryFeeTotal
        );
      }
    );
  }
});
```

The `that.state.deliverycoords` is dynamic. When I run this function, it makes the request, the browser console returns this:

> Failed to load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?destinations=-94.12788%2C45.547585&origins=1002%20Deming%20Way%2C%20Madison%2C%20WI%2053717&units=imperial&key=AIzaSyCe43xuJivO4RphF2c5PgPWdkbxlFz4mL0: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://1zjr04npqj.codesandbox.io' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I am running this code in codesandbox. Question: **How do I solve this problem and is there some sample code I can reference?**. Thanks

Comment: A workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49001011/cors-issue-with-twitter-api-calls-in-webpack-dev-server/49001123?noredirect=1#comment85542435_49001123

Comment: @Rahamin I am using the googlemaps client nodejs library. There are no ways to affix another url to this url defined in the goggle maps client nodejs library.

Comment: I ended up using the cors-anywhere workaround.